# Run and todo tabs in Pycharm

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm

I just start working in Pycharm.

My issue is that when I write a code in the editor and I run it.

The RUN tab displays: "Process finished with exit code 0".

It executes my code but I don't see it.

However, when I write the code directly in the Python Console I can see the code.

I don't know if this is totally normal or if I'm not configuring something correctly.

Also my TODO tab is not identifying the Project and displays "Found 0 TODO items in 0 files"

Thank you!

```
# Retrieve TSLA data from Quandl
tesla = quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA')

# Retrieve the GM data from Quandl
gm = quandl.get('WIKI/GM')
gm.head(5)

# Plot Data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot for gm stock
plt.plot(gm.index, gm['Adj. Close'])
plt.title('GM Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Price ($)');
plt.show()
```

Comment: Probably your code has no output while in the Python console, every returned value is printed into the console. Please share your code and we will be able to help you more specifically...

Comment: Can we see your code? You probably don't have any print statements or forgot to run your function.

Comment: # Retrieve TSLA data from Quandl
tesla = quandl.get('WIKI/TSLA')

# Retrieve the GM data from Quandl
gm = quandl.get('WIKI/GM')
gm.head(5)

# Plot Data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plot for gm stock
plt.plot(gm.index, gm['Adj. Close'])
plt.title('GM Stock Price')
plt.ylabel('Price ($)');
plt.show()

Comment: Is it working now. I tried the code, I had to wait for some seconds till the plot appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use a print statement and then ran your program. Because in pycharm, you should use the print statement to display anything